# Nginx Websockets and keepalive_timeout

Tags: nginx, websocket

I am using Nginx (nginx/1.10.2) as a reverse proxy to back end servers. I have websockets that I need to ensure a long lived connection on. I have the following lines in the `http` part of the config:

```
keepalive_timeout 0;
proxy_read_timeout 5d;
proxy_send_timeout 5d;
```

I understand the proxy_read and proxy_sends lines as per documentation. However how does the `keepalive_timeout` come into this? Should I set the keepalive_timeout to 0 to basically have no timeout? or should I set it to a high value?

What does this actually do? I didn't really find the documentation that clear on this parameter:http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_timeout

Also how will setting or disabling the keepalive_timeout affect the other static pages that I'm loading? Is it possible to set these timeout values for just the websocket? because the documentation has them under the http module so I wasn't sure if I can set them within specific locations:

```
   location /websock {
      # limit connections to 10
      limit_conn addr 10;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_pass http://backends;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

   }
```